# Should this question about the Code of Conduct be moved here from Politics Meta?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, migration, meta

I believe the "Code of Conduct" is of broader concern than just one site. Would my question [here](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3716/what-constitutes-subtle-put-down/3718#3718) be better served on Meta Stack Exchange than on Politics Meta?
If so, can someone help me with its migration please?
Even thou the other sites may not experience as many rude comments, I believe it's in the best interest of the whole of stackexchange to tackle the problem as it affects the reputation of the whole site

Answer (score 8):

You're right that discussion about the Code of Conduct concerns all sites in the network. However, in this case you're asking about a specific situation which happened on Politics Stack Exchange; a similar situation isn't likely to happen on, say, Stack Overflow or Super User. They simply don't deal with such delicate topics. The question is also about how it was/should be handled by users of Politics Stack Exchange, and communities have a bit of freedom how they interpret the global Stack Exchange rules. IMHO, it's better to let this discussion take place on Politics' own meta.

I'm not sure if the courthouse metaphor is a good one here, but if you get the feeling that you get an unfair judgement on a case, you could try and use Meta Stack Exchange as a 'place to appeal'. But, like in real life, you'll need to provide some grounds, not just saying that you don't agree with the outcome, otherwise you'll risk getting more negative reactions.

Comment: You are right, I don't want to risk getting more negative reactions. The only grounds that I would provide (which would most likely not be enough) would be that "politics really is a dirty trade" which will most likely not do me justice. I guess I could live without it :)

Comment: Is the name of the whole stackexchange not a bit at risk thou as oposed to just politics section?